# Pen drive is recognizing as a USB Internet Dongle which connects to the PC. How do the Pen drive configure well in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: usb-drive

Every time I connect my **Pen drive** it recognizes as more like a **Dongle**. The reason that I'm telling that

> *if I connect it to the PC when I'm on the* **INTERNET**, *it will
>   automatically copy all the files which are in the Dongle*.

So, I can't recognize *which one is the* **Pen drive** *when I want to safely remove the device*. I'm not sure whether it is the **Pen drive** or the **Dongle**..?

Can anyone give me a good advice how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please post (add to your question) the output from **lsusb**, with and without the '**Pen drive** connected.

Comment: @david6 **I'm not running Ubuntu from USB**. I installed Ubuntu to the _HDD on my PC_. I'm just using the Pen drive to share my files with the office..(just to copy & past).

Comment: @ErangaFernando We understand that you have installed Ubuntu on your harddrive. Please edit your question to include the output of `lsusb` as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add a volume name (label) to the partition or partitions on the USB pendrive.  This way, when you hover over the icon on the launcher it will display the volume name so you know which is the correct device.

You can add or change the volume name using Disk Utility.  Select the correct drive in Disk Utility, then click on the unmount button.  Next click the 'edit filesystem label' button and change the name to something meaningful to you.  You can now mount the device again with the mount button and it will appear in the launcher with the correct label when you hover over it.

[image: Disk Utility]

This is Disk Utility with the pendrive selected in the left frame.  To the right of this you can unmount the device and then change the label, then remount it again.  The pendrive in this example now has the label "white8" and its mount point is /media/white8

[image: white8 device in the launcher]

Now when you hover the mouse pointer over the device in the launcher it shows the label name so that you can recognise it.

Comment: _I did it..but there's one thing. There's a hidden file called .Trash-1000 in that Pen drive. Is that some kind of a virus file or something else..? I tried to remove it by formatting the drive. But couldn't, because it sends me an error called" there isn't a file to remove.." So, what is it actually? Why it is hidden always?_

Comment: Anything that starts with '.' is called a dot file, and is a hidden file.  They are used by the system for various things but in this case it is the "trash can" or "rubbish bin" or whatever it is called in your part of the world.  You should be able to delete it with Nautilus by selecting it (ctrl-h to show hidden files) and then pressing shift-delete.  If you have trouble with that then the terminal command "sudo rm /media/ERANGA\ SUBW/.trash-1000" should do it.

Comment: "sudo rm /media/ERANGA\ SUBW/.trash-1000" is the command, for clarity.  If you still can't do it, please open another question asking for help on deleting hidden files.

Comment: got it..thanx..